# Wrong Proposal Weight in collective pallet tests

Tags: substrate-node, weight, testing, pallet-collective

I have a pallet using the `propose` extrinsic of the collective pallet. one of the parameter of this extrinsic is `length_bound` which I define as follows:

```
let proposal_len:u32 = proposal.using_encoded(|p| p.len() as u32);
```

This implementation works fine when testing the pallet in polkadot.js, but when writing tests for my pallet, I get a `WrongProposalWeight` error for the `length_bound` parameter.
I tried to increase the size of the parameter like this:

```
let proposal_len:u32 = proposal.using_encoded(|p| p.len() as u32).saturating_mul(2);
```

but the error persist. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

**Edit1**

Below is the full code for the function using the collective_pallet `propose` extrinsic:

```
pub fn start_council_session(account: T::AccountId,account_type: Accounts) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo{
    //Create proposal
    let proposal0 = 
        Call::<T>::account_approval{
            account: account.clone()
        };
    let proposal = Self::get_formatted_call(proposal0.into()).unwrap();

    
    let _hash = T::Hashing::hash_of(&proposal);

    let proposal_len:u32 = proposal.using_encoded(|p| p.len() as u32);
    
    let council_member = Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::members()[0].clone();
    let council_origin= Self::get_origin(council_member);
    

    //Start Collective refererendum
    Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::propose(
        council_origin,
        2,
        Box::new(proposal.clone()),
        proposal_len,
    ).ok();
    let mut index:u32 = Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposal_count();
    index = index.saturating_sub(1);


    //debug_assert!(Some(proposal.clone())==Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposal_of(&hash));

    //Update proposal index and hash
    let proposal_hashes =  Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposals().into_iter();
    for proposal_hash in proposal_hashes{
        let prop0 = Coll::Pallet::<T,Instance2>::proposal_of(proposal_hash.clone()).unwrap();
        if proposal == prop0{
            let mut proposal_all = Proposal::<T>::new(account.clone(), Some(account_type),proposal_hash.clone());
            proposal_all.proposal_index = index;
            proposal_all.proposal_hash = proposal_hash;
            RequestedRoles::<T>::insert(&account, proposal_all);
        }
        
    }

    
    Ok(().into())
}
```

***Error occurs only during testing***

**Edit2**

I Modified the `MaxProposalWeight` in the mock runtime to be as follows:

```
fn default_max_proposal_weight() -> Weight {
sp_runtime::Perbill::from_percent(50) * BlockWeights::get().max_block
}
pub static MaxProposalWeight: Weight = default_max_proposal_weight();
```

But, I am now getting a different error:

```
thread 'tests::setting_roles' panicked at 
/home/kazu/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk- 
cff69157b985ed76/789ffb6/substrate/frame/system/src/limits.rs:314:14:
We only specify max_total and leave base values as defaults; 
qed: ValidationErrors {has_errors: true, errors: [" 
[DispatchClass::Normal] Weight 
                    {ref_time: 1024, proof_size: 0 } (total) has to be greater than Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base block) & Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic)", " [DispatchClass::Normal] Weight 
                    { ref_time: 1024, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)", "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight 
                    { ref_time: 1024, proof_size: 0 } (total) has to be greater than Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base block) & Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base extrinsic)", "[DispatchClass::Operational] Weight
                    { ref_time: 1024, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)", "[DispatchClass::Mandatory] Weight 
                    { ref_time: 1024, proof_size: 0 } (max block) must fit at least one extrinsic Weight 
                    { ref_time: 0, proof_size: 0 } (base weight)"] }
```

Kazu

Comment: Can you show us the full code maybe? It seems correct so far.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi, Added a bit more code as you asked. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @dastansam was only half of my problem.
the second error (see *Edit2*) was caused by the `BlockWeights` parameter in mock.rs, defined as shown below:

```
pub BlockWeights: frame_system::limits::BlockWeights =
    frame_system::limits::BlockWeights::simple_max(Weight::from_parts(1024_u64, 0));
```

THE BLOCK WEIGHT WAS TOO SMALL!!!
I replaced `Weight::from_parts(1024_u64, 0)` by `Weight::MAX` and the tests are now running fine.
Thanks again to @dastansam as his answer showed me the way!!

Kazu

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the values you have set for `MaxProposalWeight` and `WeightInfo` types in the `pallet_collectives::Config`. It's highly likely that you have different values set for production and test runtimes, and this might be why the error occurs only in tests. The only case this error [happens](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L854) is when the weight of the proposal is greater than `MaxProposalWeight` constant. So, maybe you are passing a really low value for that constant in the mock runtime?